# could not find function "%<>%"

Tags: r, pipe, variable-assignment

For some reason, R will recognize `%>%` (pipe operator) but not the `%<>%` (compound assignment pipe). The error I get is 'could not find function "%<>%"' - any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `%>%` from the magrittr package is loaded with `dplyr` and other `tidyverse` packages, but `%<>%` from magrittr is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load magrittr

```
library(magrittr)
x <- 4
x %<>% sqrt
x
## [1] 2
```

Note that overwriting variables can make debugging more difficult.